# access ManyToMany Object to create url with Django

Tags: django, url, many-to-many

I would like to assemble an URL of an article and send it somewhere right after saving an instance.

Everything's OK, except I'm not able to get one part of an URL, the 'category', which should be the first item of ManyToMany object.

I would like to end up with something like this:
http://www.example.com/category/article.html

the code:

```
class Categories(models.Model):
    ...
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False)
    slug = models.SlugField()

class Texts(models.Model):
    ...
    slug = models.SlugField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False)
    subtitle = models.TextField(blank=True)
    cetegory = models.ManyToManyField(to=Categories, blank=True)
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        #firstpart = self.category.all()  #returns empty list
        #firstpart = self.category        #returns empty list
        #firstpart = Categories.objects.all().filter(texts__slug = self.slug) #returns empty list
        lastpart = self.Slug              #this is ok
        return firstpart[0] + "/" + lastpart + ".html" 
models.signals.post_save.connect(post_to_twitter, sender=Texts)
```

... yes I know about reverse() and I will use it but first I want to know the arguments

thanks

Comment: What have you tried? Your URL would come from your `urls.py` and their corresponding `views.py` - and you have only posted your models.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in Texts models: 'cetegory' instead of 'category' (so self.category.all() return empty list)